# SQL Match exact set of values between two tables

Tags: sql

Okay, this is a little hard to explain, but I'll give it my best shot.

I've got two tables, we'll call them table1 and table2. table1 looks something like this:

```
ID | CampaignID | Package | GroupID
1  |     1      |    1    |   1  
2  |     1      |    1    |   2  
3  |     1      |    2    |   2  
4  |     2      |    1    |   3  
5  |     2      |    2    |   3  
6  |     2      |    3    |   3
```

etc

Table2 looks something like this:

```
ID | ClientID | ClientName | Package | OrderID
1  |   1111   | John Smith |    1    |   155  
2  |   1111   | John Smith |    2    |   155    
4  |   2222   | Dave Jones |    1    |   177  
5  |   2222   | Dave Jones |    2    |   178    
6  |   2222   | Dave Jones |    3    |   179
```

What I'm trying to do, is see if for example, John Smith has any Orders with sets of packages that match one of the Campaign Groups in table1. For the above example, John Smith's order 155 would match CampaignID 1, GroupID 2. Dave Jones's order 177 matches CampaignID 1, GroupID 1. However orders 178 and 179 don't match anything. So each set of packages in an order need to contain all the packages for a given group in order to match it

For the purposes of the select statement I have the client's id along with the orderID, and I'm simply trying to see if the packages in his order match the criteria for any campaigns.

I know I probably haven't explained this too well, so let me know what needs clarifying.

EDIT:

If lets say we search for orderID 155, clientID 1111, then the desired result would be:

```
CampaignID | GroupID
     1     |    2
```

Perhaps given that GroupID 1 also qualifies, it could return the groupID that qualifies with the largest number of packages.

Comment: please clarify, what is the relationship between `Table1` and `Table2`? `Package` or `ID` or something else?

Comment: For John Smith's order, why does GroupID 1 not match? The tables seem to be connected only through Package column? Add desired result in table form. And btw, your tables are not normalized. It sure is a good idea to read about it and change your database design.

Comment: Is there a realtionship between `ClientID` and `GroupID` you have not expressed?

Comment: The only common thing the two tables have is the package number. You're right, GroupID 1 would match as well, but what I'd be looking for is the best possible match, so GroupID 2 containing the exact same packages as order 155 would be the optimal result

Comment: GroupID is just there to separate the different sets of packages that could qualify for each campaign, there's no realtionship between it and the clientID

Comment: If orderID 155, clientID 1111, then why CampaignID | GroupID
     1     |    2. Pls calrify

Comment: Perhaps given that GroupID 1 also qualifies..... Why Group 1 only? Group 3 is also qualifying.

Comment: orderID 155 contains package numbers: 1 and 2. Since CampaignID 1, GroupID 2 has those same packages as a requirement for a match, that would be the optimal solution. GroupID 1 could also be considered a match, but since GroupID 2 has more packages, it's a better match

Comment: Group 3 doesn't qualify since it needs packages 1, 2 and 3 for it to match (and order 155 doesn't have package 3 in it)

Comment: What if there's no group matching? Should the next best group be returned?

Comment: And, again, is the schema fix or can you modify it? Cause it's really crap, no offense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
SELECT top 1 pcr1.GroupID FROM table1 pcr1
Where Not Exists (Select CampaignID from table1 as pcr2
where CampaignID = @campaignID and pcr2.GroupID= pcr1.GroupID Except
Select t2.Package from table2 as t2 where t2.OrderID = @ordID)
GROUP BY pcr1.GroupID 
ORDER BY COUNT(pcr1.GroupID) DESC
```

Given a known order and a campaign the client is trying to apply for, this gives me the group id that best matches the given order (in regard to packages), if any exists. And just because people seem to be asking, the way the tables appear here aren't exactly the way they're implemented, it's just a simplified equivalent for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this , what u want?

```
select table1.CampaignID  from Table2  
left join table1 on table1.Package =table2.Package 
where Table2.ClientID =@ClientID 
and Table2.OrderID =@OrderID
```

Comment: I'd already tried something along these lines. The problem arises from the fact that for example, searching for order 155 (clientID 1111), it returns the first 3 rows of table1, when it should return rows 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Linkedin Article with a more in depth explaination:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/profile-matching-mike-inman?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base_post_details%3Bqj89uO7mTSyVtHet9544VA%3D%3D

```
CREATE TABLE Campaign(
    ID INT,
    CampaignID INT,
    Package INT,
    GroupID INT)

CREATE TABLE ClientOrder(
    ID INT,
    ClientID INT,
    ClientName VARCHAR(20),
    Package INT,
    OrderID INT)

INSERT Campaign
(ID, CampaignID, Package, GroupID)
VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1)  
,(2, 1, 1, 2)  
,(3, 1, 2, 2)  
,(4, 2, 1, 3)  
,(5, 2, 2, 3)  
,(6, 2, 3, 3) 

INSERT ClientOrder
(ID, ClientID, ClientName, Package, OrderID)
VALUES
(1, 1111, 'John Smith', 1  , 155)  
,(2, 1111, 'John Smith', 2  , 155)    
,(4, 2222, 'Dave Jones', 1  , 177)  
,(5, 2222, 'Dave Jones', 2  , 178)    
,(6, 2222, 'Dave Jones', 3  , 179)
```

The query:

```
SELECT CO.ClientName, CampaignID
FROM    ClientOrder AS CO
JOIN    Campaign as C1
    ON    CO.Package = C1.Package
GROUP BY CO.ClientName, CampaignID
HAVING COUNT(CO.Package) = (
    SELECT COUNT(Package)
    FROM    Campaign C2
    WHERE    C1.CampaignID = C2.CampaignID)
```

Results:

```
ClientName           CampaignID
-------------------- -----------
Dave Jones           1
John Smith           1
Dave Jones           2
```